# Best way to use JSON data I retrieved from my Web API, in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

To familiarize myself with Web APIs using Rails I created (2) applications.

**POSTS** app to create some records and store some data (:name, :title, :content).

**CATALOG** app to write a Web API to retrieve the data from my POSTS app.

I used the `gem HTTParty` for my Web API calls. Here is my code from the **Catalog App**:

**new_controller.rb**

```
class NewController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    @response = HTTParty.get("http://localhost:3000/posts.json")
    @result = @response.body
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => JSON.parse(@result) }
        format.html { render "index.html.erb" }
    end
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Hello, Rails</h1>
<%= result %>
```

This successfully POSTed, in my Catalog app, the JSON data for all of my records { :id, :name, :title, :content, edit_url} from my Posts application.

So now I am looking for the best way to take the retrieved JSON data and assign in to self.attributes so that I can use these variables inside my Catalog App.

Could someone provide a nice example of this? Should I use the `rabl gem/template` inside my catalog app?

Thank You.

Comment: `format.json { render :json => JSON.parse(@result) }` that will parse the JSON to hash and then back again to JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple option to create "models" from JSON data is to use [virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) like:

```
# app/models/post.rb
class Post
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :id, Integer
  attribute :name, String
  attribute :title, String
  attribute :content, String
  attribute :edit_url, String

  def self.from_url(url)
    # using collect, assuming that posts.json is an array of posts.
    JSON.parse(HTTParty.get(url).body).collect do |item|
      new(item['post'])
     end
  end
end
```

Then you can use it like:

```
  # controller action
  @posts = Post.from_url("http://localhost:3000/posts.json")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render "index.html.erb" }
  end
  # view:
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
     Name: <%= post.name %><br/>
     Rest of the stuff: <%= h post.attributes.inspect %><br/>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I tried the option above, that you provided. In my view it is iterating through the `@posts.each do |post|` because I am receiving multiple Name: headings. However I am not getting the actually `post.name` data to show up. Any idea?

Comment: What does the response from posts.json look like? I assumed it would be like `[{"name" : "something", "id" : 1}, {"name" : "something2", "id" : 2} ...]`

Comment: First time I tried it just with `Name:` and it returned `Name:` 4 times because I have 4 records in my posts app.

Comment: Then I added 2nd line with `Rest of the stuff:` and it returns `Name:    Rest of the stuff: {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :title=>nil, :edit_url=>nil}` 4 times as well.

Comment: But what does the json look like from posts.json? :)

Comment: `["post":{"id":1, "content":"This is content #1","name":"TW","title":"Developer","edit_url":"http://localhost:3000/posts/1/edit"}}` as well as the json results for the other 3 records in the string.

Comment: that's not valid JSON, maybe it's `[{"post" : { "id" .. }}, {"post" : { "id" .. }}]` ?

Comment: Sorry, yeah it is  `[{"post":{"id":1,"content":"This is content1",...}},{"post":{"id":2,"content":"This is content2",...}}]